# Pass Contact ID from Process Builder to Flow

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, salesforce-id

I am trying to use **Process Builder** to launch a **Visual Workflow** in **Salesforce**.

The **Flow** should trigger whenever a Contact Record is created or edited to meet certain criteria: `"Qualification" = "Marketing Qualified"`

I have an input text only variable in my **Flow** called `{!varContactID}`. When I try and set the value of the variable using a Reference Type in **Process Builder**, I can't select `Contact ID` from the dropdown menu - only the `Contact ID (18)` field is available.

As a work around, I set the `{!varContactID}` variable as a Formula Type using the Formula `[Contact].Id`. I've also tried using the Reference Type with the `Contact ID (18) field - but neither seems to work. I don't see any errors with the Flow - but the value I'm trying to update on the Contact Record isn't populating.

I've tested my **Flow** manually (via Flow URL) and it worked as expected. I also created an **Assignment Element** at the beginning of my **Flow** and manually assigned a `Contact ID` to the `{!varContactID}` variable. The **Flow** worked as expected here as well.

So, it appears that the problem here lies in **Process Builder** or at least how **Process Builder** is communicating to **Flow**. Any ideas?

Comment: is that my answer works for you?

Answer (score 4):

In the process builder you need use reference as follows:

[image: process bulider]

Sample flow looks like this:

> This flow, takes the id from parameter and updates an checkbox to true of the Contact record.

[image: flow]